# vallinajs get xml and parse to json

Tags: javascript, json, xml, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Guys I'm trying to get this xml using promises and fetch:

https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml

This is how I'm trying:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
var myInit = { method: 'GET',
               headers: myHeaders,
               mode: 'no-cors',
               cache: 'default' };

fetch("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml")
     .then(function(response){console.log(response);});
```

I get response, but I don't know how to read this xml or convert to json to read it. Any help please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch XML with fetch api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693982/how-to-fetch-xml-with-fetch-api)