# Error Cannot read property 'Lon' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I need to read a jason file to place some data in a table, this is being done but nevertheless the program gives me an error

this reads a file generated from a database in Postgresql

The data that I am reading are as follows

```
<Locations>
<Ce>188</Ce>
<Id>1</Id>
<Lat>10.330385</Lat>
<Lon>-75.50266</Lon>
<N_2>1000</N_2>
<N_3>2000</N_3>
<Nombre>mce_cartagena1</Nombre>
<Ult_t>2019-07-08 21:03:25</Ult_t>
<alarm>0</alarm>
<error i:nil="true"/>
</Locations>
<Locations>
<Ce>-53</Ce>
<Id>2</Id>
<Lat>4.789242</Lat>
<Lon>-74.054513</Lon>
<N_2>1000</N_2>
<N_3>2000</N_3>
<Nombre>mce_santo_tomas</Nombre>
<Ult_t>2019-07-08 21:02:30</Ult_t>
<alarm>0</alarm>
<error i:nil="true"/>
</Locations>
```

Here I do the reading of the data

```
        var url = 'http://190.85.6.14/mills_status/Api',
                    params = {
                        method: 'GET',
                        mode: 'cors',
                        redirect: 'follow',
                        headers: new Headers({
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        })
                    };

                var request = new Request(url, params);

                fetch(request).then(r => r.json())
                    .then(datos => {
                        tabla(datos);
                    })
                    .catch(e => console.error('Something went wrong',e));
```

and here I go through the data to place them in a vector

```
        function tabla(datos) {
                contenido.innerHTML = '';
                for (var i = 0; i <= datos.length; i++) {
                    cordenadasLo[i] = parseFloat(datos[i].Lon);
                    cordenadasLa[i] = parseFloat(datos[i].Lat);
                    nivel[i] = parseInt(datos[i].alarm);
```

he reads the data correctly, but the error persists

```
Something went wrong TypeError: Cannot read property 'Lon' of undefined
    at tabla (JavaScript.js:80)
    at JavaScript.js:71
(anonymous) @ JavaScript.js:73
```

Comment: You aren't reading JSON data from the server. You're reading XML. It doesn't read properly because `r.json()` isn't finding `json` data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch XML with fetch api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693982/how-to-fetch-xml-with-fetch-api)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you're trying to parse XML as JSON, but this doesn't work since XML and JSON are two completely different things.

To fix this, replace your `r.json()` call with code for parsing XML. I adapted code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41009103/3988232) to do this.

```
fetch(request).then(r => r.text())
    .then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
    .then(datos => { tabla(datos); })
    .catch(e => console.error('Something went wrong',e));
```

**Note:** You'll need to adapt your `tabla` function to traverse your data using something like `datos.getElementsByTagName("Locations")`

If you're using node.js, you could look into using [`xml-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js), instead.