# JavaScript how to determine when AJAX calls are done in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've spent the last few days trying to tackle this issue and have read all sorts of solutions on StackOverflow and other sites.

I'm building a site that grabs XML data from an outside source and then gets more XML depending on the results to build a network graph.  **The problem** is that I have to essentially wait until this loop of AJAX calls (which may loop into more AJAX calls) is finished before drawing.

I don't know if this just has an especially high cognitive load, but it really has me stumped.

**My Code:**

```
function cont(outerNodes) {

    for (var i = 0; i < outerNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = outerNodes.pop();
        getXML(node["label"], node["id"]);
    } 
    // I want the code to wait until loop is done, and then draw.
    draw(nodes, edges);
}

function getXML(term, fromId) {

    var url = someURL;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(result) {
            var outerNodes = process(result, fromId, term);
            cont(outerNodes);
        }
    });

}
```

**Note:** I understand I may be completely misunderstanding JavaScript synchronicity here, and I very likely am.  I have used callbacks and promises successfully in the past, I just can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

If I have not been totally clear, please let me know.

I did try implementing a counter of sorts that is incremented in the process() function, like so:

```
if (processCount < 15) {
    for (var i = 0; i < outerNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = outerNodes.pop();
        getXML(node["label"], node["id"]);
    }
} else {
    draw(nodes, edges);
}
```

However, this ended up with several draw() calls which made my performance abysmal.

Comment: It's better to use promise for this scenario. Otherwise you can add a counter, check the counter number is reached and then executed the draw method.

Comment: I have used the counter method.  While it works, it ends up with multiple draw calls which makes my performance something awful. I am unsure how promises would be implemented here.

Comment: How do you write the code? can you paste it in the question?

Comment: Added to the bottom.

Comment: Your code actually has some mistakes, when did you increase the processCount?

Comment: As it says in the question, in the process function.  Please let me know where the mistakes are, as it runs fine just with awful performance.

Comment: ok. i missed that part. You can check my answer below. You should consider to use Promise or call it in callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are nice new well-supported APIs and language constructs we can use.  The [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), and [`for...of` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

The Fetch API uses Promises.  Promises can be awaited.  The `for...of` loop is aware of `await` and won't continue the loop until the `await` has passed.

```
// Loop through, one-at-a-time
for (const node of outerNodes) {
  // Make the HTTP request
  const res = await fetch(someUrl);
  
  // Do something with the response here...
}
```

Don't forget a `try`/`catch` (which also works with `await`), and check [`res.ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok).

Comment: Thank you! I believe I follow, I'm just not totally sure where the getXML function works in here?  I may just be misunderstanding the solution.

Comment: @Zmalski The call to `fetch()` replaces your AJAX call.  And then, you'll want to call `res.text()` and use `DOMParser()` to parse the XML.  (This answer has more details on parsing XML after you get your Fetch response:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41009103/362536)

Comment: I see, so if I follow you correctly, the fetch gets the data, you convert it to text then parse it to XML?  Which I can then feed into my process() function?

Comment: @Zmalski Yeah, basically.  `fetch()` actually returns a `Response` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), which comes back as soon as the HTTP response headers are complete.  So, at the time the `fetch()` promise resolves, the response body doesn't have to be there yet.  This allows you to check the headers if you want (or in your case, you should check `res.ok`) and cancel the request rather than streaming some long response you may not want.  When you call `res.text()`, the response body is buffered and given to your code when the promise resolves.

Comment: @Zmalski (continued) So, once you have the response as text, you then parse its XML, as you said.  You can use the resulting `Document` in the exact same way you use the one from your normal JavaScript.  So, you could do `document.querySelector('label')` or whatever you need.

Answer (score 2):

Brad's answer changes the code to by synchronious and to me that defeats the purpose. If you are constantly waiting on all request to be finished then it could take a while, while normal browsers can handle multiple requests.

The problem you have in your original questions is with scope. Since each call to `cont(outerNodes)` will trigger it's own scope, it has no idea what are calls are doing. So basically if you call `cont(outerNodes)` twice, each call will handle it's own list of `outernodes` and then call `draw`.
The solution is to share information between the different scopes, which can be done with one, but preferably two global variables: 1 to track active processes and 1 to track errors.

```
var inProcess = 0;
var nrErrors = 0;

function cont(outerNodes) {

    //make sure you have outerNodes before you call outerNodes.length
    if (outerNodes) {
      for (var i = 0; i < outerNodes.length; i++) {
          var node = outerNodes.pop();
          inProcess++; //add one more in process
          getXML(node["label"], node["id"]);
      } 
    }

    //only trigger when nothing is in proces. 
    if (inProcess==0) {
      // I want the code to wait until loop is done, and then draw.
      draw(nodes, edges);
   }
}

function getXML(term, fromId) {

    var url = someURL;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(result) {
            var outerNodes = process(result, fromId, term);
            inProcess--; //one is done
            cont(outerNodes);
        },
        error: function() {
            inProcess--; //one is done
            nrErrors++; //one more error
            cont(null); //run without new outerNodes, to trigger a possible draw
        }
    });

}
```

Please note that I track `nrErrors` but dont do anything with it. You could use it to stop further processing all together or warn the user that the draw is not complete.

**[important]** Keep in mind that this works in `javascript` because at best it mimics multithreading. That means the the call to `inProcess--;` and then right after `cont(outerNodes);` is always execute directly after eachother.

If you would port this to a true multithreading environment, it could very well be that another scope/version of `cont(null);` would cut in between the two lines and there would still be multiple draws.

Comment: No, my code does not make it synchronous.  It uses `await` to wait on asynchronous tasks before going to the next item.  Isn't the whole point of the question that they only want one at a time?  And furthermore, the loop in my answer could still be done even if you wanted to make all the requests at the same time, while still using `await` to deal with the response.  My actual preferred method is to use Semaphore (https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-semaphore) so I have control over the number of things running at the same time, but that seems out-of-scope for this question.

Comment: If you await every single ajax call, then they run and finish in the exact order you call them in, making it synchrone. Even if the actual ajax call is asynchrone, your cont function is synchrone. And the goal isnt to make it one at a time. Each call can add x number of request to be made and they all need to finish. 10 calls adding 10 new calls, dont need to wait a 100 times. They could theoratically run 10 a time and finish 10 times faster.

Comment: If you want to do multiple at a time, use a semaphore, like I said.  This is perfectly appropriate if you're making requests for a lot of small data, or from different servers.  Rarely is this appropriate though for larger things.  Of course, the browser can only pipeline a handful of simultaneous requests and it will transparently queue for you, but you'll find that if you queue up a couple hundred requests, the browser will cancel them en masse.  (It would be nice if it didn't, but this is reality.)

Comment: It wasn't an attack, I was just stating that your code changes the way the loop works. Then I did exactly what this site is for: I explained why it wasn't working and what needed to be done and gave an example of how to do it. Obviously there are a hundred other ways to do this and things that need to be taken into account, but I'm not hired to do a performance/code review. I tried to help him understand what was going on and why his logic is failing. So he can solve the next problem himself.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this question should be using either promise or callback.
If you really want to avoid promise or callback(Although i don't know why...)
You can try with a counter.

```
    let processCount = 0;
    
    // Increasing the processCount in getXML callback method
    function getXML(term, fromId) {
        var url = someURL;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(result) {
                processCount++;
                var outerNodes = process(result, fromId, term);
                cont(outerNodes);
            }
        });

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < outerNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = outerNodes.pop();
        getXML(node["label"], node["id"]);
    }
    while (processCount < outerNodes.length) {
        // do nothing, just wait'
    } 

    draw(nodes, edges);
```

Comment: did you callback all successfully executed?

Comment: I don't understand the question, apologies.

Comment: Never mind, just look at Brad's answer, it should be the best answer for your scenario.

Answer (score -1):

If after testing it many times, you know that it will never take more than say 5 seconds... you can use a setTimeout.

```
function cont(outerNodes) {

        for (var i = 0; i < outerNodes.length; i++) {
            var node = outerNodes.pop();
            getXML(node["label"], node["id"]);
    } 


// Display a 5 second progress bar here

 setTimeout(function(){ draw(nodes, edges); },5000); 

}
```

Comment: This is a particularly bad answer.  Load time will vary, significantly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still has the added issue of multiple draw calls, just with a timeout.