# Fetch data from management software API

Tags: javascript, c#, xml, api, webapi

I have a store management software, i wanted to fetch its API and display products on my website.

```
<member name="T:XDWebAPI.Controllers.ItemController">
        <summary>
        This controller includes all operations needed to work with Items/Products
        </summary>
    </member>
    <member name="M:XDWebAPI.Controllers.ItemController.#ctor">
        <summary>
        Default constructor
        </summary>
    </member>
    <member name="M:XDWebAPI.Controllers.ItemController.Get">
        <summary>
        Get all items from the database
        </summary>
        <returns>A list of ItemBE</returns>
    </member>
    <member name="M:XDWebAPI.Controllers.ItemController.GetAllItemStockForWarehouse(System.Int32)">
        <summary>
        Get all items stock on a specified warehouse from the database
        </summary>
        <returns>A list of SimpleItemStock</returns>
    </member>
    <member name="M:XDWebAPI.Controllers.ItemController.GetItemStockForWarehouse(System.Int32,System.String)">
        <summary>
        Get specific item stock on a specified warehouse from the database
        </summary>
        <returns>SimpleItemStock object representing the item stock</returns>
    </member>
    <member name="M:XDWebAPI.Controllers.ItemController.Get(System.String)">
        <summary>
        Get an item identified by keyId
        </summary>
        <param name="keyId">The item identifier</param>
        <returns>The ItemBE object representing the item</returns>
    </member>
```

I have this code on "WebAPI.xml" from the software.
How can I access the database data from this API and send it to website?

Comment: I guess duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693982/how-to-fetch-xml-with-fetch-api)

Comment: For what i understood from the weather API has all data on that page and then is just to make a fetch data from there. My problem is that i have the xml file with that "member" and i want to openn that "member" and then probably it will display data and is just to fetch it. I don't know how to access for example "<member name="M:XDWebAPI.Controllers.ItemController.GetAllItemStockForWarehouse(System.Int32)">". I don't understand where is that member pointing to

Comment: Do I need to get request for "WebAPI.xml" and then get "<member name="M:XDWebAPI.Controllers.ItemController.GetAllItemStockForWarehouse(System.Int32)">"?
Will that make it the request from database?

Comment: Well, I got this wrong then