# Split returned value to just phone number and text

Tags: javascript, json, string, https

I am using a HTTPS get request to pull information from a server. It is pulling back the entire string but it looks very messy I am just looking for the phone number and text to display. I am struggiling to be able to split the output so I can show just what I need.

The API documentation is

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| messageID | Text-Connect message ID |
| sentTo | Mobile number message was sent to |
| keyword | Keyword used |
| receivedFrom | number used to receive message |
| receivedOn | Date/Time message received |

The code it is using is

```html
script>

        async function fetchMoviesJSON() {
            const response = await fetch('https://my.text-connect.co.uk/api/receivedmessages/xml?apiKey=3c5yclTjgTlBqsYdjMUaxiN4QjnIhw&from=last&pp=50');
            const receivedFrom = await response.text();
            return receivedFrom;
        }
        fetchMoviesJSON().then(function (receivedFrom){ document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = receivedFrom; })


</script>
```

We tried to use different variable declarations and contacted the installer to find out what we could do but they wasn't much help

This is the returned sting:

```
0Successful request2237507830447507203646Non-specified079095754252023-10-30 10:46:06Test (Incoming - +447799XXXXXX )
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags for your questions (PHP is not involved here, you are making an HTTP request with JavaScript). Also, you should share the current result you get from this service.

Comment: I have updated the article, my apologies.

Comment: The API you are using seems to give XML responses. Your `response.text()` is the issue here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch XML with fetch api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693982/how-to-fetch-xml-with-fetch-api)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with XML, it only seems to work with HTTPS pull and JSON string

Comment: When I tried to use it, it gave an XML response. This service is badly documented. Change your `.text()` to `.json()` then.

Comment: Still not working?

Comment: Does anyone else have any advise?